# Difference between *f and (*f) in C?

Tags: c, dereference, brackets, dead-code, cppcheck

CppCheck (v1.72) says there is a difference when using `(*f)` or just `*f`. The this case

```
void test(float *f)
{
    float a = 0.0f;
    if(*f>a)
    {
        (*f) += 0.01f;
        if(*f<a) *f=a;
    }
}
```

cppCheck says "Opposite conditions in nested 'if' blocks lead to a dead code block, where as

```
void test(float *f)
{
    float a = 0.0f;
    if(*f>a)
    {
        *f += 0.01f;
        if(*f<a) *f=a;
    }
}
```

makes cppCheck happy. What exactly is the difference?

Comment: No  difference. Anything else?

Comment: yes, why does cppcheck make a difference here when there is none?

Comment: Because in First `if` you asked `*f > a` and in nested (second) `if` you asked the opposite -- Probably the CppCheck can't see that `*f` was modified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference. Ideally, cppcheck should be warning you in both cases, because your code isn't logical.

However, cppcheck isn't infallible. Don't assume that if cppcheck shows no issues, there aren't any. It's just another useful tool that helps spot bad code that might otherwise go undetected.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this issue here on stackoverflow. I have created a ticket about this issue on cppcheck's [bug tracker](http://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/7405#ticket).